# приведение типов к (void *)

Tags: c

Есть вот такое извращение

```
/* Parse a pointer.  Must parse whatever is produced by '%p' in sprintf(). */
static int duk__parse_pointer(const char *str, void **out) {
    const unsigned char *p;
    unsigned char ch;
    int count;
    int limit;
    long val;  /* assume void * fits into long */

    /* We only need to parse what our minimal printf() produces, so that
     * we can check for a '0x' prefix, and assume all hex digits are
     * lowercase.
     */

    p = (const unsigned char *) str;
    if (p[0] != (unsigned char) '0' || p[1] != (unsigned char) 'x') {
        return 0;
    }
    p += 2;

    for (val = 0, count = 0, limit = sizeof(void *) * 2; count < limit; count++) {
        ch = *p++;

        val <<= 4;
        if (ch >= (unsigned char) '0' && ch <= (unsigned char) '9') {
            val += ch - (unsigned char) '0';
        } else if (ch >= (unsigned char) 'a' && ch <= (unsigned char) 'f') {
            val += ch - (unsigned char) 'a' + 0x0a;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /* The input may end at a NUL or garbage may follow.  As long as we
     * parse the '%p' correctly, garbage is allowed to follow, and the
     * JX pointer parsing also relies on that.
     */

    *out = (void *) val;
    return 1;
}
```

компилятор сообщает

> duk_minimal_printf.c:126:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>     *out = (void *) val;

я не достаточно хорошо знаю С, поэтому если бы не запускал этот проект лично, то подумал бы что этот код даже не скомпилируется, но все же он работает.
я понимаю, что это не критично, но хочется устранить, т. е. к какому типу необходимо привести *val*, что бы компилятор перестал выдавать указанное  предупреждение?

Comment: Видимо, вам нужен `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @zed похоже на то. Проект нормально скомпилировался и запустился. Перед релизом проведу тесты. Спасибо!

Comment: Там не приводить надо, а изначально объявить с более подходящим типом, таким как `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @kisssko, спасибо! я понял это с ответа zed.

Comment: @zed, почему не ответом?